# Android studio module naming convention

Tags: android, naming-conventions

I am looking for a thorough android studio module naming convention suggestion.

If the name of the module is `app free` what is the best name convention for that?

- app-free
- appfree
- app_free
- appFree

Comment: As a comment, I'm getting a bunch of crashes when trying to use dashes. New modules can't even create themselves.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no convention for android module names.

But since the packageNames are all lowercase and dot-separated, I'll used `appfree`.

BTW if you want to build a "free" version of something, take a look at Gradle' flavors instead of modules.

Comment: See https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors and applications like https://stackoverflow.com/a/19327232/603270

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any documentation on Gradle modules (aka projects) naming conventions. You can always see what other projects are doing. A quick [Github search](https://github.com/search?q=include+filename%3Asettings.gradle&type=Code) shows that all of the above options are used, by some pretty big projects no less.